# URL Encoding using a loop

Tags: string, for-loop, urlencode

I am trying to use the following function to return the string with every space replaced with a %20. However, it only prints out the '%20' in each of the print statement outputs. I am also trying to omit replacing the first space in a string. Any ideas? I know that there is library and a .replace() method that exits to solve this, but I want to use a for loop and conditionals.

```
def urlEncode(text):
    result = ''
    for i in text:
        if i == ' ':
                i = '%20'
                result = result + i
    return result
print(urlEncode("Lighthouse Labs"))
print(urlEncode(" Lighthouse Labs  "))
print(urlEncode("blue is greener than purple for sure"))
```

output is:
%20
%20%20%20%20
%20%20%20%20%20%20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey you need to add the characters that are not space too, right? Have a look in the edited script.

```
def urlEncode(text):
    result = ''
    for i in text:
        if i == ' ':
            i = '%20'
            result += i
        else:
            result += i
    return result


print(urlEncode("Lighthouse Labs"))
print(urlEncode(" Lighthouse Labs  "))
print(urlEncode("blue is greener than purple for sure"))
```

Edit, additional answer: -how to omit first space

```
def urlEncode(text):
    result = ''
    counter = 0
    for i in text:
        if(counter == 0 and text[counter] == ' '):
            result += i
        elif i == ' ':
            i = '%20'
            result += i
        else:
            result += i
        counter += 1
    return result
```

Comment: Hey @billybadass . Thanks. That works - but how to omit the first space?